# c++/c# Marshal a struct to get a fixed pointer

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, struct, marshalling

I have an older app which accepts dll plugins. Each plugin has a function that creates a new instance of a "widget". This function identifies the new "widget" instance by returning a unique **int**. In the c++ plugin template I have it's done by declaring a new widget **struct** and returning its pointer cast as an **int** as a unique identifier (not my idea, but I have to work with it):

```
struct widget {
    ...
};

int widget_instance (HWND hwnd) {
    widget* myWidget = new widget;
    ...
    return (int) myWidget;
}
```

I'm working on a c# plugin for this app and I need to replicate this mechanism in c#. How do I declare a struct inside a function, so that each time the function is called it returns a fixed, non-changing pointer to the newly declared struct? My code so far:

```
public struct Widget {
   ...
}

public static int widget_instance(uint hwnd) {
    Widget w = new Widget();
    ...
    IntPtr myWidget = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(w));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(w, myWidget, false);
    return (int) myWidget;
}
```

Does this seem right? Do I need to "pin" the struct for this to work as c++ does?

EDIT: To elaborate: the unique ID is not just a simple "cookie" **int**, it's in fact used later on in the c++ template to access the **struct** instance by casting the ID as a pointer:

```
widget* w = (widget*) WidgetID;
w->firstElement = 123;
```

I assume the c# equivalent would be:

```
widget w = (widget)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)widgetID,typeof(widget));
w.firstElement = 123;
```

Comment: In general, AllocCoTaskMem (COM allocator) is **not** equivalent to C++ "new". What piece of code is supposed to do the release in your example? (PS: an HWND shoud be declared as an IntPtr or a HandleRef, not a uint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to imply that the returned integer identifier is just a cookie, and isn't treated by the app as a pointer. That would mean that the app never performs operations on the widget, but always asks the plugin to perform the operations on the app's behalf. If that's the case then there's no reason why you can't use your own scheme for assigning cookie identifiers. So...

You could add a "cookie" member to your Widget class, and a static "next cookie" member for assigning cookies. This would be a simple and semantically sound implementation. Obviously it would require thread-safety measures. It would also avoid the C++ technique of casting the "this" pointer to an int, which you say you don't like although I think it's perfectly fine.

The C++ pointer-to-int cast technique might serve a second purpose in addition to providing a unique identifier. When the app gives the plugin a cookie, the plugin can find the widget directly and at zero runtime cost by casting the cookie back to a pointer. Although that's hardly safe. But I don't think you can do that in C# anyway.

Your proposed C# code means that for every widget the app asks for, you wantonly create and initialize a second widget. If you really want to mimic the C++ technique so that your cookies are guaranteed to be unique process-wide, as opposed to just unique within the single plugin, then you could just allocate a one-byte block but don't initialize it. Or even a zero-sized block, but I'm not quite certain that that would yield unique addresses.

Comment: Good point, and your 3rd paragraph describes what's going on (I updated my question with this info). The integer is not just a cookie, later on it's cast as a pointer. If the app wants the plugin to perform an operation on a widget, it calls a plugin function with the widget "ID" as a parameter. You said you don't think I can do this C#. Shouldn't I be able to cast an int as a pointer if the pointer was declared as fixed/unmanaged?

Comment: Yes, I suppose you could do it as you describe. But then you're adding even more wastage: every time you call Marshal.PtrToStructure() you create a new widget and copy the data from the unmanaged object into it. That's a lot of allocation and copying. So you lose all the performance advantage of casting the cookie back to a pointer (and then some.) I don't see much to recommend this technique. Using the pointer as the cookie is fine in unmanaged C++, but the cast is unsafe; and neither technique has any place in managed code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct, since `AllocCoTaskMem` allocates the memory from the *unmanaged* COM allocator.

The memory is released or relocated only with the `FreeCoTaskMem` or `ReAllocCoTaskMem` functions, respectively.